# What is the right place for registerCssFile in Yii?

Tags: php, css, yii

I'm new to Yii.

Is it right to place registerCssFile call inside an action of controller?

My opinion is that right place for this is inside views

E.g I create some chunk of user menu and include it inside **some** of my views. I got separated css file for user menu and I don't want to care about including this `user_menu.css` inside each action or controller which view uses this user menu. So I use this code inside `parts/user_menu.php` view:

```
<?php
    Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCssFile(yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/css/user_menu.css', 'screen');
?>
<ul class="user-menu">
...here comes menu
```

Is it right or I must include this css file inside of each action or controller instead?

Maybe there are some style guides about this? Any links appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't speak for an "official" right place, but I have a custom base Controller which all of my controllers extend. I place my global `registerCssFile()` calls in the `init()` method of this base controller, so they are automatically registered on the whole site.

If you are re-using partial view files a lot I could see registering the CSS *in* the view I guess *but*...

It probably makes the most sense to just included all the CSS for the whole site in the `init()` controller method, and *then combine and compress it using [extensions like these](http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=compress)*.

(Unless one view has a LOT of custom CSS not used anywhere else on the site, maybe.)

EDIT: As mentioned below by briiC.lv, using `themes` means you'll want to keep all CSS in your view/layout files, separate from the Controller code.

Comment: Yes, I'm already include all everywhere-used css and js in init(), but I didn't know about compression extensions in Yii, thanks

Comment: i was also using init (or beforeAction in main Controller) but i found  this approach not flexible when you planning add themes to your site. If i must have include themes in yii app i put registerCss and registerScript directly into layout file, so switching between themes doesn't include unnecessary code and i doesn't need to think and add many IF statements in init "if (theme=='default') { /* register default.css */ } else if (theme=='pink') { /* register pink.css and register pink.js */}".

Comment: @briiC.lv Why think in terms of `if (theme == 'default')`? Why not just data dispatch? You can put the control of theme everywhere up to external configuration files for some preprocessor!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if I were you, I would forget about `registerCssFile` completely and always used `registerPackage` only. This way you can swap your entire styling everywhere changing one string in one well-defined place.

Two options:

1. You make the base class for your controller classes and put all of the `register` statements in `beforeRender` there. This way you'll need separate controller class for every section on the website which require different styling.
2. You use modules. Then you go and place `register` calls in the `init` call of the module class.

Do not put `registerCss` calls in views *ever*. This will backfire at you very quickly. It does not matter whether you have small website or large one.

I personally prefer using `beforeRender` always, as this means that assets will be processed only for your "pages", that is, route responders which render something hopefully HTML-like to the client.